# Android - Is this possible to get android device's system configuration?

Tags: android

I would like to get the device's system configuration information including RAM, ROM, External Memory, Processor details in which my app is running. 
I am a begineer, could you please help to get started?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have a look at these "Build" class at android-sdk page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html.

```
// Device model
String PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;

// Android version
String AndroidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

eg:

```
public String getDeviceName() {

    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;

    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize(model);
    } else {
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}

private String getAndroidVersion() {
    return android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
}

private String capitalize(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char first = s.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
    }
}

private String getDeviceId() {
    String deviceId = "";
    final TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null) {
        deviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
    } else {
        deviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
    return deviceId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Build` class should contains all the info you need. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

```
Nested Classes
class   Build.VERSION   Various version strings. 
class   Build.VERSION_CODES Enumeration of the currently known SDK version codes. 
Constants
String  UNKNOWN Value used for when a build property is unknown.
Fields
public static final String  BOARD   The name of the underlying board, like "goldfish".
public static final String  BOOTLOADER  The system bootloader version number.
public static final String  BRAND   The consumer-visible brand with which the product/hardware will be associated, if any.
public static final String  CPU_ABI The name of the instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.
public static final String  CPU_ABI2    The name of the second instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.
public static final String  DEVICE  The name of the industrial design.
public static final String  DISPLAY A build ID string meant for displaying to the user
public static final String  FINGERPRINT A string that uniquely identifies this build.
public static final String  HARDWARE    The name of the hardware (from the kernel command line or /proc).
public static final String  HOST    
public static final String  ID  Either a changelist number, or a label like "M4-rc20".
public static final String  MANUFACTURER    The manufacturer of the product/hardware.
public static final String  MODEL   The end-user-visible name for the end product.
public static final String  PRODUCT The name of the overall product.
public static final String  RADIO    This field was deprecated in API level 14. The radio firmware version is frequently not available when this class is initialized, leading to a blank or "unknown" value for this string. Use getRadioVersion() instead.
public static final String  SERIAL  A hardware serial number, if available.
public static final String  TAGS    Comma-separated tags describing the build, like "unsigned,debug".
public static final long    TIME    
public static final String  TYPE    The type of build, like "user" or "eng".
public static final String  USER
```

Use `Build.*` to get the info you need.